# Which data visualization when running GLMM?

Tags: data-visualization, binomial-distribution, glmm, inverse-gaussian-distribution

I'm analysing correct response rate and response time of participants on a task.
For the first one, I ran a **mixed effect logistic regression**:

```
glmer (CR ~ Group * Var2 * Var3 + NDG + (1 |ID),
                     data = df,
                     family = binomial (link = "logit"))
```

When I have an interaction effect, I investigate simple effects and I also plot my data, for instance, box plot/bar plot for correct response rate according to Group and Var2 (and I put the little "*" for significant effects). However, the plot of correct response rate does not represent well my model outcomes (log odds). And for the interaction it can be rather misleading (as explained [in this blog post](https://janhove.github.io/analysis/2019/08/07/interactions-logistic)).

**What is the best way to represent my data in this case?**

For the second one, I ran a GLMM with inverse gaussian distribution (after having read  [Lo and Andrews, 2015](https://janhove.github.io/analysis/2019/08/07/interactions-logistic)):

```
glmer (RT ~ GroupC * Var2 * Var3 + (1|ID),
                    data = TSTdf1,
                    family = inverse.gaussian (link = "identity"))
```

I this case, for an interaction effect I plot mean RT (with se) and graphically represent significant effect with "*". But again, my model is not comparing means (and means are not the best way to represent RT distribution). I was thinking about plotting flat violin which is better to my mind but I'm not sure it will be as easy to put my stars on it (with ggsignif).
**What would you recommend in this case?**

A visual example would be appreciated (maybe with paper using this kind of visualisation) and any suggestion would be appreciated :-)))

(My supervisors like "*"... so that's why I need to put them on my plots)